# Associated type in protocol extension

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I want to create a protocol and extension which I will use in three different view controllers for API loading.

```
protocol WebAPILoader {

    // URL of remote resource
    var url: URL? { get set }

    // Array supposed to store loaded data.    
    associatedtype T
    var data: [T] { get set }

    // Function loading them
    func loadNextPage()
}
```

Every VC downloads different data using its endpoint so I want my function to choose which endpoint to use based on data type, like this:

```
extension WebAPILoader {

    mutating func loadNextPage() {

        guard let url = self.nextURL else {
            return
        }

        let dataType = type(of: data)
        var endpointLoader: ((URL?, @escaping (dataType? ,URL?, Error?) -> Void) -> ())? = nil

        switch data {
        case is [DataType1]:
            endpointLoader = DataType1().getData

        // Other cases...

        default:
            return
        }


        // EndpointLoader usage...
    } 
}
```

But Xcode keeps telling me various errors forbidding me from use of T as a Type in my extension. Is there any way of achieving that?

Comment: Huh, that's weird – the compiler doesn't like switching over a `[T]` with a conditional type casting pattern to some other array type. I would say that's a bug, given that `if let data = data as? [DataType1] {...}` works just fine. Feel free to [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: Although note that your default implementation of `loadNextPage()` is `mutating`, which is incompatible with your non-mutating protocol requirement. You need to make them either both mutating or non mutating.